# In Excel, How can I add values in a specific column if I have a checkbox type spreadsheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

The Excel sheet is linear with column B being the distance walked each day. Across are a column for each participant. As they join the walking group each day, I'd like to keep a count on total distance for each user.

[image]

Is it possible to create a formula to go across the top of this sheet that calculates the sum of the Distance for each initial with a checkbox marked?

Comment: Are the check boxes linked to the cell they are sitting in? Are you open to just using a "X" to mark the cells instead of a checkbox? It will make calculating much easier on your part.

Comment: Yes, I am open to just using X instead of a checkbox in the fields. I don't know sumif and sum product functions where I point to add only the specified values. If I just wanted to count the checkmarks I would use a COUNTIF function but I don't know how to link to the conditional sum of the distance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`SUMIF`](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/SUMIF-function-5fd078db-e5f8-4726-b08f-74fd0064e7fe?ui=en-US&rs=en-NZ&ad=NZ) is really similar to [`COUNTIF`](https://support.office.com/en-NZ/article/countif-function-4764f197-0127-49fa-9f5a-b188177b6db4). If you don't use checkboxes, `=SUMIF(D$3:D$6;"<>";$B$3:$B$6)` should do the trick:

[image]

As you can see from the function wizard in the screenshot, `SUMIF` can take 3 arguments, **Range**, **Criteria**, and **Sum_range**.

- **Range** is the range of cells you want evaluated against some criteria.
- **Criteria** is the criteria you want to check against, in the formula above we check for nonblank cells - I found the syntax used, among other places, in [this thread](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-formulas-and-functions/344003-using-sumif-with-non-blank-cells.html).
- **Sum_range** is the range you want to sum, it is an optional argument, and if you omit it the formula will sum the range you evaluate.

Note that since we check against nonblank cells, any value in the cells of the column will make the distance for that day will be summed, even a whitespace or an empty string. If you only want to check against x-es, put `"x"` instead of `"<>"` as the Criteria.

Comment: Thanks! That worked. I wasn't as familiar with SUMIF but that was very clear and concise. Made sense.